# How to set break points in all versions of a method?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

In Visual Studio 2017.

```
class Base { public: virtual M() = 0; const char* m_name; };
class ADer : public Base { M() override { do_work(); } };
class BDer : public Base { M() override { do_more_work(); } };
class CDer : public Base { M() override { do_less_work(); } };
class CCDer : public DerC { M() override { do_no_work(); } };
```

I'm looking for a way to set break points on all implementations of `M` with a conditions that `strcmp(m_name, "Ludvig")==0`.
I.e. I'm wanting to break on `M` but I don't know of what type the object is that in run-time will have `m_name` set to `Ludvig`.

I tried setting a functional break point with function name "*Der::M" but no matching functions could be found.
Also, setting multiple functional breakpoints using regex strings like that seem to put the break points on the entry to the function, in which case `m_name` might not be set, so will the conditional always fail in that case?

Any solution to this?

Comment: just put a breakpoint on every derived class. I don't understand why you can't do that.

Comment: @bolov [I sense](https://laughtrek.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Screenshot-2019-01-18-at-12.35.00-PM.png), neckutrek wants to have that done automagically.

Comment: There are over a hundred derived classes. And I need to do this for over 20 values of `m_name`. So I'm looking for something automatic yes :)

Comment: An answer, if one exists, will be specific to your IDE or debugger.   I'm not aware of any which will do this though.   Which means you will need to manually set an break in each derived function.       An alternative would be to make `M()` non-virtual, have it call a (preferably protected) pure virtual function (say `Mvirt()`), then override `Mvirt()` as needed.   All you need to do then is set a breakpoint in `M()` before it calls the virtual.

Comment: @Peter, that would imply refactoring the name of the method in all 100 derived classes. Could there be a simpler way I wonder. Seems like a regex could do the job instantly, that's why I expected VS to support this.

Comment: @neckutrek - unlike the solution you're seeking, most IDEs readily support replacing all instances of a string with another - using a regex if not something else.   And quite a few IDEs support doing that operation for all files in a project.   This means the option I suggested could be implemented easily, within a few minutes.   I'm not aware of any IDE that attempts to automatically set a series of breakpoints like you ask.   It may be easy to implement but, practically, isn't the sort of feature many developers would demand, so vendors would not bother.